# Synchronizing three threads with Condition Variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have three threads in my application, the first thread needs to wait for a data to be ready from the two other threads. The two threads are preparing the data concurrently.
In order to  do that I am using condition variable in C++ as following:

```
boost::mutex mut;       
boost::condition_variable cond;
```

**Thread1:**

```
    bool check_data_received()
    {
         return (data1_received && data2_received);
    }

    // Wait until socket data has arrived
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mut);
    if (!cond.timed_wait(lock, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(200),
        boost::bind(&check_data_received)))
    {

    }
```

**Thread2:**

```
    {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mut);
        data1_received = true;
    }
    cond.notify_one();
```

**Thread3:**

```
    {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mut);
        data2_received = true;
    }
    cond.notify_one();
```

So my question is it correct to do that, or is there any more efficient way? I am looking for the most optimized way to do the waiting.

Comment: "most optimized way" to "do the waiting" is a surprisingly powerful contradiction :)

Comment: @sehe I know doing waiting is not good, and will effect the parallelism of the work. That's why I want to know,if there's another way to achieve what I want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want a semaphore here, so you can wait for two "resources" to be "taken".

For now, just replace the mutual exclusion with an atomic. you can still use a cv to signal the waiter:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

boost::mutex mut;       
boost::condition_variable cond;     

boost::atomic_bool data1_received(false);
boost::atomic_bool data2_received(false);

bool check_data_received()
{
    return (data1_received && data2_received);
}

void thread1()
{
    // Wait until socket data has arrived
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mut);
    while (!cond.timed_wait(lock, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(200),
        boost::bind(&check_data_received)))
    {
        std::cout << "." << std::flush;
    }
}

void thread2()
{
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(rand() % 4000));
    data1_received = true;
    cond.notify_one();
}

void thread3()
{
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(rand() % 4000));
    data2_received = true;
    cond.notify_one();
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread_group g;
    g.create_thread(thread1);
    g.create_thread(thread2);
    g.create_thread(thread3);

    g.join_all();
}
```

Note:

- **warning** - it's essential that you know only the waiter is waiting on the `cv`, otherwise you *need* `notify_all()` instead of `notify_one()`.
- It is **not** important that the waiter is *already* waiting before the workers signal their completion, because the predicated `timed_wait` checks the predicate before blocking.
- Because this sample uses atomics and predicated wait, it's not actually critical to signal the `cv` under the mutex. However, thread checkers will (rightly) complain about this (I think) because it's impossible for them to check proper synchronization unless you add the locking.

Comment: tahnks for your answer but what's the difference with respect to my original code. You're still using the predicated wait, but for workers thread you replaced the lock_guard with atomic_bool. What performance improvement will this do?

Comment: no locking to read/write the shared state (bools). If you expect continuous loads, it could be beneficial to "spin" on the condition without a mutex here. Then you've arrived at lockfree synchronization. However, there's no blocking wait in lock-free programming, so if there's no continuous work, this will end up just burning CPU while spinning. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486552/boostlockfreespsc-queue-busy-wait-strategy-is-there-a-blocking-pop/22487474#22487474

Comment: If you want I can show you a solution based on thead_barrier later. Have to go now

Comment: ok whenever you have time, I will be happy to see the thread_barrier

Comment: Ok. Here's the spinning version (actually, it would mostly be useful without the sleep in `thread1` since, if you need it locking would not be a problem (see my answer solution) and otherwise it would pin the CPU 100%) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/119b35fea470acfe

Comment: And here's the version with the thread-barrier: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0cee581a228fa4f. Note, I decided to make the number of workers variable, and show how the barrier can be reused. In fact, you can vary the semantics by constructing the barrier with a custom `completion function`. This resembles an inverse semaphore, if you will. Also, I'm not sure what the performance characteristics here would be. I guess it comes down to profiling, profiling, profiling (as always)