# Can I use boost named_semaphore in place of ACE_SEMAPHORE as I am trying to move from ACE to boost libraries?

Tags: c++11, boost, semaphore, boost-thread, ace

I am moving my code from ACE library support to boost library support. I need to replace ACE_Semaphore. It seems C++11 doesn't support semaphore methods. I have seen named_semaphore in boost. Another choice I saw was to go for POCO semaphore where in I have to include POCO libraries. Kindly give me suggestions as to which is the best way to move forward.

Edit: This is for intra process thread synchronization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: yes.

If for intra-process synchronization, you can simply emulate one with a mutex+condition variable:

[C++0x has no semaphores? How to synchronize threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792449/c0x-has-no-semaphores-how-to-synchronize-threads/19659736#19659736)

> Note though, usually a mutex + condition variable will do, as the concrete condition doesn't usually take the form of a counter. (E.g. [Synchronizing three threads with Condition Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809537/synchronizing-three-threads-with-condition-variable/22812187#22812187))

For interprocess synchronization you use the named semaphore. An example: [How to limit the number of running instances in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545789/how-to-limit-the-number-of-running-instances-in-c/22545891#22545891) Note that there are implementation differences¹.

¹ e.g. named_semaphore in boost allocates its own shared resource, while in ACE it's assumed the user allocates it from existing shared space. In boost, you obviously also can, as long as your platform supports native synchronization primitives in shared memory

Comment: It is for intra process communication. I will edit my question as well. Thanks for the info.