# How to stop an std::thread from running, without terminating the program

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

I am trying to learn `std::threads` from `C++11` to make a threading system.

I was wondering if there is a way to stop a thread from running (Not sleeping, but really destructing the thread or so to speak) without terminating the whole program.

I know `std::join` exists, but that forces a thread to wait till all threads return.

Is there another way to handle this? (For example for making a `ThreadPool` class without having to block a thread?)

Comment: no such possibility out of the box. but
you can try boost::thread or write your own implementation of this functionality

Comment: `std::thread` knows pretty much everything a thread implementation has to know: 1.) creating a thread 2.) joining it. You don't need anything else. Unfortunately gracefully "killing a thread" is actually asking the thread to exit and the joining it while it is exiting. Sometimes implementing this is platform dependent but with events/conditions you can often implement it platform independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ `std::thread` class is really just a minimal interface layered on top of some more complete implementation-defined threading package.  As such, it only defines a tiny amount of functionality -- creating new threads, `detach`, and `join`.  That's pretty much it -- there's no standard way of managing, scheduling, stopping/starting/killing threads or doing much else.

There is a `native_handle` method that returns an implementation-defined type which can probably be used to do what you want, depending on the implementation.

Comment: I don't really get this. std::thread has about all the functionality that underlying thread implementations have (modulo the stuff that can't be used portably or isn't safe to use anyways. All the important other bits in the respective "threading package"s is also there (condition variables (a.k.a. event), (recursive) mutex (a.k.a. critical section), (unique) locks helpers, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this thread_pool will help you:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::phoenix::arg_names;

boost::atomic_size_t counter(0ul);

class thread_pool
{
  private:
      mutex mx;
      condition_variable cv;

      typedef function<void()> job_t;
      std::deque<job_t> _queue;

      thread_group pool;

      boost::atomic_bool shutdown;
      static void worker_thread(thread_pool& q)
      {
          while (optional<job_t> job = q.dequeue())
              (*job)();
      }

  public:
      thread_pool() : shutdown(false) {
          for (unsigned i = 0; i < boost::thread::hardware_concurrency(); ++i)
              pool.create_thread(bind(worker_thread, ref(*this)));
      }

      void enqueue(job_t job) 
      {
          lock_guard<mutex> lk(mx);
          _queue.push_back(job);

          cv.notify_one();
      }

      optional<job_t> dequeue() 
      {
          unique_lock<mutex> lk(mx);
          namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

          cv.wait(lk, phx::ref(shutdown) || !phx::empty(phx::ref(_queue)));

          if (_queue.empty())
              return none;

          job_t job = _queue.front();
          _queue.pop_front();

          return job;
      }

      ~thread_pool()
      {
          shutdown = true;
          {
              lock_guard<mutex> lk(mx);
              cv.notify_all();
          }

          pool.join_all();
      }
};
```

Example of use: **[live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f46f98ff90d13a82)**

Comment: nice use of `while` `(` *declaration* `)`

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to non-cooperatively stop a thread from running with standard C++. That doesn't mean it's impossible, but you may need to go back to your systems native handle.

For a standard conforming way you can use synchronization primitives (e.g. an `std::atomic<bool>`) to set a kill flag from the outside and read it within the thread. But it  still has to be the thread that finishes on its own.